# Creating tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a table using SQL and being a beginner I have no idea where I'm going wrong..

This is my code:

```
    CREATE TABLE 'test_11' (
  `Company_Name` varchar(160),
  `Company_Number` varchar(8),
  `Care_Of` varchar(100),
  `PO_Box` varchar(10),
  `Address_line1` varchar(300),
  `Address_line2` varchar(300),
  `Post_town` text,
  `County` varchar(50),
  `Country` text,
  `Post_Code` varchar(20),
  `Category` varchar(100),
  `Status` varchar(70),
  `Country_of_Origin` text,
  `Dissolution_Date` date,
  `Incorporation_Date` date,
  `Accounting_refday` int(2),
  `Accounting_refmonth` int(2),
  `Next_due_date` date,
  `Last_made_up_date` date,
  `Accounting_category` text,
  `Returns_next_due_date` date,
  `Returns_last_made_up_date` date,
  `Num_mort_changes` int(6),
  `Num_mort_outstanding` int(6),
  `Num_mort_part_satisfied` int(6),
  `Num_mort_satisfied` int(6),
  `SIC_code1` varchar(170),
  `SIC_code2` varchar(170),
  `SIC_code3` varchar(170),
  `SIC_code4` varchar(170),
  `Num_gen_partners` int(6),
  `Num_lim_partners` int(6),
  `URL` varchar(47),
  `Change_of_name_date` date,
  `Company_name_previous` varchar(160)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET =latin1;
```

Could someone help me and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What is going wrong? What is the error? Remove the quote marks

Comment: it says: error 1064 (42000): you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test_11'(
'Company_name' varchar(160),
'company_number' varchar (8),
'car' at line 1

Comment: Remove the quote marks - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the syntax near the table name. Remove the quote marks from `test_11`.

```
  CREATE TABLE test_11 (
  `Company_Name` varchar(160),
  `Company_Number` varchar(8),
  `Care_Of` varchar(100),
  `PO_Box` varchar(10),
  `Address_line1` varchar(300),
  `Address_line2` varchar(300),
  `Post_town` text,
  `County` varchar(50),
  `Country` text,
  `Post_Code` varchar(20),
  `Category` varchar(100),
  `Status` varchar(70),
  `Country_of_Origin` text,
  `Dissolution_Date` date,
  `Incorporation_Date` date,
  `Accounting_refday` int(2),
  `Accounting_refmonth` int(2),
  `Next_due_date` date,
  `Last_made_up_date` date,
  `Accounting_category` text,
  `Returns_next_due_date` date,
  `Returns_last_made_up_date` date,
  `Num_mort_changes` int(6),
  `Num_mort_outstanding` int(6),
  `Num_mort_part_satisfied` int(6),
  `Num_mort_satisfied` int(6),
  `SIC_code1` varchar(170),
  `SIC_code2` varchar(170),
  `SIC_code3` varchar(170),
  `SIC_code4` varchar(170),
  `Num_gen_partners` int(6),
  `Num_lim_partners` int(6),
  `URL` varchar(47),
  `Change_of_name_date` date,
  `Company_name_previous` varchar(160)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET =latin1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bfc68)